# Gist Plugin for Sublime Text not pulling in all Gists

Tags: sublimetext2, gist

I'm using the Gist plugin for Sublime Text (2 in my case) from [Condemil](https://github.com/condemil/Gist).

I've been using it to pull in commonly used code snippets which I store as Gists and it's been working perfectly until recently.

It still pulls in gists, but only the recent ones, and a lot of my older ones aren't being pulled in - they're completely ignored.

In the settings, I have it pulling in everything, not just starred gists, so that's not the issue. I also know that it can only pull in 100 gists at a time (the github API limit apparently) but it's not even doing that. I barely have more than 100 gists and it's not pulling in almost half of them.

Any thoughts?

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest filing an issue with the plugin's author...

Comment: Yeah, that's probably best, I'll do that thanks.